# How can I type the "@" symbol via remote desktop with a Swedish keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, remote-desktop

I am running Remote Desktop to connect from my iMac with Snow Leopard to a Windows box at work that runs Windows 7 Professional. The connection is done over ssh.

When logged in to the window box I can use Alt + Tab to switch between programs, I can also see that when using emacs pressing Alt registers as Meta (which is what I have set it up as). However if I want to type a @ which on my Swedish keyboard is Alt + 2 nothing happens. The same is true for { and [ and so on.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> did the trick for me (on Swiss German keyboard).

Comment: This also works on a Norwegian keyboard

Answer (score 3):

Does  <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> work? This is a combination for @ in bootcamp.

For the other keys:

- <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>  to get {
- <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>  to get }
- <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>  to get [
- <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>  to get ]

Comment: No unfortunately it does not work. I can do ctrl + alt + 2 to get "@" but since ctrl + alt collides with other keyboard mappings I would much rather have it work with just alt + 2.

Comment: Did you try AltGr+2?

Comment: I think alt + ctrl maps to AltGr since there is no AltGr on the Mac keyboard. However, pressing ctrl + alt interferes with other commands in some programs, like using alt as meta in emacs.

Answer (score 3):

On my keyboard alt-G also did not work, however, alt-E works for the EURO sign. After some trying I found the **alt-Q** is the solution for the at (@) sign on the remote desktop (which is a Windows system).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could set up another keystroke to produce @ via system preferences/language & text/text/symbol and text substitution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the character palette.

System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard tab
Check "Show Keyboard & Character Viewers in menu bar"
(If necessary, press Input Sources... and enable Keyboard & Character Viewer)

Then open the Character Viewer from the menu bar, locate the character you need, and double-click it to insert it.

Comment: That is one solution it's just that it is very very slow.

Answer (score 0):

I use Cord and Danish keyboard and I get the ampersand (&) using

Right-<kbd>alt</kbd> + right-<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not an answer, but on a UK keyboard @ and " swap places from Mac to Windows

<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>    <kbd>2</kbd>   is @ on Mac, " on Win
 <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>'</kbd>  is " on Mac, @ on Win

Answer (score -1):

Shift + ± worked for me when I typed all the characters on the keyboard using Shift key

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>alt</kbd> + 0 worked for me. (under mac its produce ø, under vm win7 its produce @)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Comment: ?!
It's just because none of previous answer worked for me so i add the way i solve my use case.

Maybe that will help someone.

Don't understand your comment.

Answer (score -3):

alt gr (the alt symbol on the right hand side) plus semicolon worked for me

Comment: And what keyboard does your answer apply to, Swedish?

Comment: Mac keyboards don't have an alt/gr key